# Remove table from scanned Document

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

Im trying to clean a image from the straight lines that form a table in a scanned document, so far I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any-image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26
So I find the lines pretty accurately, but I dont know how to remove them: this is the lines extracted from the image(note that each box is filled with text I want to preserve)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dQDk.jpg)

This is a image of the original image, the sensitive parts have been censored
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirLv.jpg)

and this is my code

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

def box_extraction(img_for_box_extraction_path, cropped_dir_path):   
img = cv2.imread(img_for_box_extraction_path, 0)  
# Read the image
    (thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255,
                                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Thresholding the image
    img_bin = 255 - img_bin  # Invert the image

    cv2.imwrite("Image_bin.jpg", img_bin)

    # Defining a kernel length
    kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1] // 40

    # A verticle kernel of (1 X kernel_length), which will detect all the verticle lines from the image.
    verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))
    # A horizontal kernel of (kernel_length X 1), which will help to detect all the horizontal line from the image.
    hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))
    # A kernel of (3 X 3) ones.
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

    # Morphological operation to detect verticle lines from an image
    img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
    verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
    cv2.imwrite("verticle_lines.jpg", verticle_lines_img)

    # Morphological operation to detect horizontal lines from an image
    img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
    horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
    cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines.jpg", horizontal_lines_img)

    # Weighting parameters, this will decide the quantity of an image to be added to make a new image.
    alpha = 0.5
    beta = 1.0 - alpha
    # This function helps to add two image with specific weight parameter to get a third image as summation of two image.
    img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)
    img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
    (thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # For Debugging
    # Enable this line to see verticle and horizontal lines in the image which is used to find boxes
    cv2.imwrite("img_final_bin.jpg", img_final_bin)
    # Find contours for image, which will detect all the boxes
    #im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_final_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Sort all the contours by top to bottom.
    #(contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")



    # For Debugging
    # Enable this line to see all contours.
    # cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    # cv2.imwrite("./Temp/img_contour.jpg", img)


box_extraction("41.jpg", "./Cropped/")
```

Comment: Could you show the original image too?

Comment: @Warpstar22 I added a image of the original.

Comment: @nathancy thanks, I will take a look, they look promising